# Split list of countries in alphabetical order using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to split a list of countries in alphabetical order using Angularjs.
Somewhat like A : America , Australia   B: Brazil, Bhutan ... 
The list is coming from a table named countries. I tried to apply angularjs filter on the first alphabet of the country name but failed. Do I have to create a custom filter for it?

Comment: where do you want to use that? Some textfield with drop down list?

Comment: Like this ( http://www.infoplease.com/countries.html#ALPHA-A )

Comment: What does the data look like in your controller? Is it coming from a service? A jsfiddle or some code showing what you've tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I am going to answer my own question  finally got it working. 
I was pulling a list of countries from a postgres db in the following format:

```
{"alpha2":"ao","alpha3":"ago","numeric":"024","country":"Angola"}
```

I wanted to split the list of countries in alphabetical order like this :

[Example] http://infoplease.com/countries.html#ALPHA-A

I finally got it working by writing a custom filter:

```
angular.module('countryFilter', []).filter('cfilter', function() {
return function(input,x) {
var groups = [];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
if (input[i].country.substring(0,1) == x)
groups.push(input[i]);
} return groups; }
});
```

and using it as :

```
ng-repeat="data in countries | cfilter:'A'
{{data.country}}
```

Do let me know if there is any better way for doing this...

Comment: nice solution, i noticed code inside the custom filter gets executed twice though - is this a normal behaviour for angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

This is another possible solution without the use of a filter
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2456-Grouping-Nested-ngRepeat-Lists-In-AngularJS.htm

He creates a new array with a label and the data. The advantage is that in the template you don't have to name all the possible letters.

For my own I take the first letter of the client from the object and store that in the label. In that way I only get the letters I used.

In customer I have stored an array with objects.

```
for(var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++){

    var customer = customers[i];


    if(customer[ 'title' ].substring(0,1) !== groupValue){

      var group = {
        label : customer[ 'title' ].substring(0,1),
        customers : []

      };

      groupValue = customer.title.substring(0,1);
      groups.push( group );

    };


    group.customers.push( customer );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort Item List is a jQuery plugin that creates iOS-style sticky headers similar to those seen in the Music and Contacts apps on Apple devices
check link :

http://www.codingprogrammer.com/tutorialdemo/jquery-tutorial/sort-items-alphabetically-jquery-2/